# How to arrange a list of tuples so that the tuple associated with the highest value compared to other tuple is removed and returns the maximum one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

```
val = [(200, []), (300, [500, 200]), (400, [100, 200, 300]), (400, [])]
largest_val_arrangement(val)
[(200, []), (300, [500, 200]), (400, [100, 200, 300])]
```

so now `(400, [])` is poped out because `(400, [100, 200, 300])` has more elements than it.

Comment: Is order in the final outcome important?

Comment: no order does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `sort` according to the length of the list, and use a dictionary so the last written key "wins".

Then convert back to `tuple` or `list` or ... leave as `dict`:

```
val = [(200, []), (300, [500, 200]), (400, [100, 200, 300]), (400, [])]

def largest_val_arrangement(val):
    return tuple({k:v for k,v in sorted(val, key = lambda t : len(t[1]))}.items())

largest_val_arrangement(val)
```

result:

```
((200, []), (400, [100, 200, 300]), (300, [500, 200]))
```

This method, like the `sort` it uses, has `O(log(n)*n)` complexity, (`dict` has `O(1)` average complexity).

But one-liners aren't always the most efficient solutions. Here using `sort` is unnecessary, when a good old loop with a marker dict works in `O(n)`:

```
def largest_val_arrangement(val):
    d = dict()
    for k,v in val:
        if k not in d or len(d[k]) < len(v):
            d[k] = v

    return tuple(d.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

O(n) solution

```
>>> val = val = [(200, []), (300, [500, 200]), (400, [100, 200, 300]), (400, [])]
>>>
>>> seen = {}
>>> for k, lst in val:
...:    if len(lst) > len(seen.get(k, [])):
...:        seen[k] = lst
...:        
>>> list(seen.items())
[(200, []), (300, [500, 200]), (400, [100, 200, 300])]
```

Comment: a good lesson for us: `sort` is overrated in those kind of problems.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, and the dict solution even preserves order in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

Other option, using a default dictionary from collections:

```
val = [(200, []), (300, [500, 200]), (400, [100, 200, 300]), (400, [])]

from collections import defaultdict
tmp = defaultdict(list)

for x in val:
  if len(x[1]) > len(tmp[x[0]]): tmp[x[0]] = x[1]

res = [(k, v) for k,v in tmp.items()]
print(res)

#=> [(200, []), (300, [500, 200]), (400, [100, 200, 300])]
```

Comment: that 's `O(n)` so it's better. nitpick: use `defaultdict(list)` instead of `lambda:[]`. I came back to add a similar answer (using standard dict, not default) when I found your solution.

Comment: Merci fort the tip @Jean-FrançoisFabre